# Why doesn't the php.ini file change in laradock?

Tags: php, laradock

Installed docker, docker-compose and laradock.
Changed settings in nginx and /etc/hosts.
The site is open and the flight is normal.
I just noticed that the error display does not work. Then I found out that it was necessary to register `display_errors On` in **php.ini**.

In my .env version of php 7.2 In laradock, in the file `/home/serii/Web/laradock/php-fpm/php7.2.ini`, changed the `display_errors` setting to **On**.

Then I run `sudo docker-compose down` and rebuild for `php-fpm sudo docker-compose build worker php-fpm`

Then `sudo service apache2 stop && sudo docker-compose up -d nginx php-fpm mysql workspace`

In workspace, php.ini is in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`
And there display_errors Off.
Only for some reason php.ini in phpinfo () is located in a different path, but such path does not exist in workspace.

[image]

I've been rummaging in the net for half a day and can't find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because the laravel.ini doesn't reload. you will find some configuration saved in laravel.ini you have to force recreate to reload it

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build php-fpm
```